# Lottie animation not working

Tags: android, lottie

How can I use Lottie Animation in Android? I tried but the animation doesn't run.
How to start the JSON animation?
I want to use a custom loading animation instead of using regular circular progress bar.

Comment: Please try to be more specific in your question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the Lottie Animation using the following steps:

Add the Gradle dependency to your app

```
dependencies {  
compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.0'
}
```

Add the view to Your Layout XML:

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/animation_view"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:lottie_fileName="preloader.json"//this is the JSON animation stored in assets folder
    app:lottie_loop="true"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true" />
```

In your Activity or Fragment init the view:

```
private LottieAnimationView animationView;
animationView = (LottieAnimationView) findViewById(R.id.animation_view);
```

Play/Cancel the Animation using:

```
animationView.playAnimation();
animationView.cancelAnimation();
```